# Am I incorrectly using PromptOptions?

Tags: javascript, botframework

I'm trying to create a `ChoicePrompt` for my *chatbot*, but for some reason I can't import the `PromptOptions` interface. When I try including it in the `botbuilder-dialogs` imports:

```
const { DialogSet, WaterfallDialog, ChoicePrompt, WaterfallStepContext, PromptOptions } = require('botbuilder-dialogs');
```

VS Code doesn't recognize it as being part of the package, and try using it when creating the prompt in the `WaterfallStepContext`:

```
async (step = new WaterfallStepContext()) => {
       const semOptions = ["Fall", "Winter", "Summer"];
       options = new PromptOptions({ 
              prompt: `What semester are you currently in, ${this.name}?`, 
              choices: semOptions 
       });
       return await step.prompt("semPrompt", options);
}
```

I get a unhandled error:

```
TypeError: PromptOptions is not a constructor
```

I reinstalled the latest version `botbuilder-dialog` package several times but to no avail. Can anyone offer any insight as to what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: See this MDN page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_a_constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PromptOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/javascript/api/botbuilder-dialogs/promptoptions?view=botbuilder-ts-latest), is an interface with configurable options you pass in the prompt. You don't need to 'construct' it via new PromptOptions.

Wrt you question you could do something like:

Add 'ChoiceFactory' utilities

```
const { WaterfallDialog, ChoiceFactory, ChoiceFactory, ConfirmPrompt, TextPrompt } = require('botbuilder-dialogs');
```

In your dialogs constructor you add the prompt and add it to the dialogSet:

```
 this.addDialog(new ChoicePrompt(CHOICE_PROMPT_NAME));
```

In your dialogstep you call the prompt and pass the options

```
    async Step(stepContext) {
        const SEMOPTIONS = ['Fall', 'Winter', 'Summer'];
        return await stepContext.prompt(CHOICE_PROMPT_NAME, {
            prompt: `What semester are you currently in, ${this.name}?`,
            retryPrompt: 'Please select one of the options',
            choices: ChoiceFactory.toChoices(SEMOPTIONS),
            style: 5
        });
    }
```

Btw: It seems you are using C# / Python classes in your Javascript code. The SDK documentation for JS is [located here](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/javascript/api/botbuilder/?view=botbuilder-ts-latest):